# Insert list of column with stored procedure

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, dynamic-sql

I have a Matlab's script where I would like to use stored procedures instead of sending all the instructions to the server. The problem is that I have to deal with string variables containing differents columns like this one for example :

`listColumns = '(column1, column2, column3, ... columnN)';`

What I would like to know is how make a stored procedure using dynamic SQL to make insertions with a list of columns as a string input argument ? Is it possible or do I need to change my script to make it more easy ?

This is pretty new for me, I have tried more simplistics stored procedures where I only need one column and it worked well, but I'm stuck with this for the moment :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION myfunction(
    tablename regclass, 
    listColumns regclass,
    listColumnsTarget regclass)
    RETURNS void
    LANGUAGE = 'plpgsql'
AS $$
BEGIN
    EXECUTE format('INSERT INTO ' %s %s '(SELECT ' %s ' FROM anotherTable)',
    tablename, listeColumns, listColumnsTarget);
END
$$;
```

I expected to get the stored procedure to work, but it failed and I get an syntax error...

Comment: For identifiers (column names, table names) you should use `%I`  in the format function as that properly deals with quoting. Also `listColumns` and `listColumnsTarget` should be defined as `text`. A variable of type `regclass` can only hold a single table name, never a column name and never more than one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`regclass` type can holds just one identification of some database object (described by one row of `pg_class` system table). You cannot to use a `regclass` type for passing a column names, because just columns are not a tables. `regclass` type is special and check the value against system tables.

```
postgres=# select 'xxx'::regclass;
ERROR:  relation "xxx" does not exist
LINE 1: select 'xxx'::regclass;
               ^
```

Postgres has special type for SQL identifiers - `name`. And if you want to pass more values, you should to use a array of names - `name[]`. But for input from outside is better to use usual `text` type and process necessary operations inside the function. Using `name` type doesn't help to us in this context.

What is necessary? Escaping - it is sanitization against syntax errors or SQL injections. For example - the identifiers: `fubu, boo-boo, AA` should be translated to safe list of identifiers: `fubi, "boo-boo", "AA"`. This step is very important

Postgres has not any functions for this fork for list, but we can write own function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION sanitize_identifiers(text)
RETURNS text AS $$
  SELECT string_agg(quote_ident(v), ',') 
    FROM unnest(string_to_array($1, ',')) g(v)
$$ LANGUAGE sql;
```

Now, we can write function like:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION foo(tablename regclass,
                               columns text)
RETURNS void AS $$
BEGIN
  -- should to print valid SQL
  RAISE NOTICE '%',
    FORMAT('INSERT INTO %s SELECT %s FROM tab',
            tablename,
            sanitize_identifiers(columns));
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Result:

```
postgres=# select foo('Test','a,b,c,C');
NOTICE:  INSERT INTO test SELECT a,b,c,"C" FROM tab
```

Comment: Thank you for your explanations, I will try your solution !